# Hadoop single node installation

Tags: hadoop

I installed hadoop single node(version 1.0.3) on ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The problem is that whenever I start the node, the jobtracker status remains stagnant as "INTIIALIZING" and after executing jps some 5-6 times, the Datanode process also vanishes. I tried to check out the log files and I managed to find this error:

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310
```

Sometimes everything works fine while on the other hand sometimes the datanode does not start at all. Can anyone suggest as to why such an inconsistency is taking place?

The relevant files are as follows:

*core-site.xml*:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://127.0.0.1:54310</value>
<description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
  scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
  uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
  the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
  determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

*mapred-site.xml*:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>127.0.0.1:54311</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

*hdfs-site.xml*:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi can you check once namenode is running or if it is not running you need to run once.
And it need create dir in /app it need permissions.
Type this bellow commands:

sudo mkdir /app

sudo chown $USER /app

hadoop namenode -format

Then start all nodes and check after few minutes. It will run all nodes..................

Answer (score 0):

You can see tuotrial at : http://www.improgrammer.net/hbase-installation-ubuntu/

udo mkdir /app

sudo chown $USER /app

hadoop namenode -format